# How to access config file in flutter using bloc architecture

Tags: flutter, config, bloc

In my Flutter app, I separate the build environments dev and prod. To achieve this I created an AppConfig class extending an inherited widget.

```
class AppConfig extends InheritedWidget {
  AppConfig({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.clientId,
    @required this.redirectUrl,
    @required this.discoveryUrl,
    @required this.scopes,
    @required this.apiBaseUrl,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  final String title;
  final String clientId;
  final String redirectUrl;
  final String discoveryUrl;
  final String apiBaseUrl;
  final List<String> scopes;

  static AppConfig of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppConfig>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}
```

In the views it works fine and I can access the config file like this: `_config = AppConfig.of(context);`

I am following the BLoC architecture pattern in my app. Is it possible to access the config file on the bloc or networking layer? e.g. in my API provider. The problem is, that I have no context in these classes. The goal would be something like this.

```
  Future<dynamic> get(String url) async {
    _config = AppConfig.of(context);
}
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'am looking for same solution. Please provide if you find one.

Update: Check this link, it is solution with singleton:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ready-to-go-e59873f9d7de

Answer (score 2):

`AppConfig` can be a global singleton and you don't need to use `InheritedWidget` for this, instead use a plain dart class. So you can use a service locator to set up the instance. Then access the instance from anywhere on your app without the need for context object.

To set up the service locator, you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package. Detailed examples are available on the documentation.